# Datepicker - close calendar popup on button click.

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I press my button and datepicker opens. If I click away from the popup the popup closes as expected. If I click the button to open datepicker then click it again to close it, it remains open.

**html**

```
<div id="datepicker-group" class="input-group date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='select_dates'>Select dates</button>
    <input class="form-control" name="data" type="hidden" placeholder="" id='test'/>        
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker-group").datepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    multidate: true,
    clearBtn: true,
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below funciton, when modal popup click close button:

```
$(".close").click(function(){
  $('.datepicker').hide();
});
```

Comment: I want just the single button to open and close. Also have had some issues with .hide() as it hides the whole div not just the pop up, making it impossible to select dates again.